# Enabling/disabling legend with click event for Mschart, Rgraph, Telirk Chart

Tags: .net, mschart, fusioncharts, rgraph

With Fusion Charts, there is a click event that can toggle the visibility of the legend. Is this same functionality available for MSchart, Rgraph, and Telrik? I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer for MS Chart.

If you are using the Windows Forms version built in to the .NET 4 Framework, you can programmatically remove the legend(s) by clearing the `Chart.Legends` collection:

```
_chart.Legends.Clear();
```

This will remove any `Legend` object from the chart, so if you want to switch between displaying and not displaying the legend, you would need to save the `Legend` object locally and `Add` it to the collection when you want to display it again.
(Alternatively, it is also possible to remove the `Legend` object from the `Legends` collection directly in the designer.)

If you are using the WPF version available in the WPF Toolkit, probably the most convenient way to hide the legend is to set the `Width` and the `Height` in the `Chart.LegendStyle` to zero in *XAML*:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
```

In order to re-display, the `Width` and `Height` need to be set to non-zero values. In contrast to the Windows Forms chart, you need not re-define the `Legend` object with this approach.